# How to change the machine key on ASP.NET production site and migrate encrypted passwords

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have currently the following problem, I'm using ASP Identity to handle Authentication, but it is showing me errors because of the XSRF token, one of the solutions is to setup a machinekey setting in web.config. I already have one set, but its from my development computer, so I think I need to generate a new one for my production environment, the problem is that if I change it my current users would not be able to login, I haven't found something yet on how to make this change, how to migrate encrypted passwords into a new machine key.

Comment: Put the error received in your quesiton.

Comment: @soheilalizadeh Im not sure how to show the "error" its just that if I change the machine key all passwords are rejected even if they are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine key is not used for [password hashing](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs) in Identity (v2 and v3)

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the case, most information about password hashing associated with the machine key is outdated or applies for Identity v1. I haven't tested if on a ASP Web Api site the access / bearer tokens are affected by this change though